# GMP, Windows, program with gmp library is failed, if executable file was moved into another computer

Tags: c++, windows, dll, mingw, gmp

I installed gmp into Windows using following steps: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/gmp/. I used msys and  MinGW. And I implemented gmp library into my project.

My project compiled by Visual Studio C++ , run and tested successfully.

After that I moved the executable file of my project into another windows server. I copied all generated .dll files into this server. When I run executable file, it is crashed:

```
Symbol-SearchPath: '.;C:\ATF\homes\IDR_4267781;C:\ATF\homes\IDR_4267781;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;SRV*C:\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;', symOptions: 530, UserName: 'SYSTEM'    
OS-Version: 6.1.7601 (Service Pack 1) 0x112-0x3
C:\ATF\homes\IDR_4267781\dbsync_extract.exe:dbsync_extract.exe (000000013F2A0000), size: 40734720 (result: 0), SymType: '-nosymbols-', PDB: 'C:\ATF\homes\IDR_4267781\dbsync_extract.exe'   
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll:ntdll.dll (0000000077090000), size: 1740800 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll:kernel32.dll (0000000076F70000), size: 1175552 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7601.17514

....

C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll:CRYPTBASE.dll (000007FEFCE70000), size: 61440 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll', fileVersion: 6.1.7600.16385
C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\dbghelp.dll:dbghelp.dll (0000000018830000), size: 1556480 (result: 0), SymType: '-exported-', PDB: 'C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\dbghelp.dll', fileVersion: 6.4.7.1
000000006ACE618A (libgmp-3): (filename not available): _gmpn_set_str
000000006ACC235B (libgmp-3): (filename not available): _gmpf_set_str
000000013F962727 (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F89C3E6 (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F5A2ACA (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F40C863 (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F40B59E (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F401886 (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F52A02E (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F52A391 (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F5365E4 (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F3DD986 (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F35E807 (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F35EE0C (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F2F72ED (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F2F4E0F (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F2A18A4 (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F2A19EE (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F2A1E17 (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F2A1EDC (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000013F2A103F (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
0000000140130752 (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
000000014013065E (dbsync_extract): (filename not available): (function-name not available)
0000000076F8652D (kernel32): (filename not available): BaseThreadInitThunk
00000000770BC521 (ntdll): (filename not available): RtlUserThreadStart
Unknown exception raised
```

Why my program in the my computer works well, but in the another computer does it is failed?

Comment: Have you installed GMP in the second server?

Comment: No, I only copied gmp.dll into second server. I moved also all generated .lib, .h and so on files into second server from the first server. And set environment variable GMP_HOME( that I used) into second server.

Comment: We want that user should not to install gmp library and he should only used .dll file.

Comment: Are you sure there is a libgmp-3.dll file in the second server? And apart from that, why don't you link gmp statically?

Comment: Yes, I copied it into second server. How can I link gmp statically? We use cmake to  compile our project.

Comment: cmake does not compile, but calls a compiler. in case of gcc compilers you need to add -static in linking and have the static libraries of gmp, at the link you posted.

Comment: I used this command: [ ./configure --prefix=/d/Temp/gmp-5.0.1-install --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-static --enable-shared  ] . And .lib and .dll were created without any depends from machine